# Extract and rename JSON object to different format

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing

I'm requesting venue data from the Foursquare API but it is not returned in the geoJSON format.  I haven't worked with JSON before and I do not have any idea how to approach doing this.

Will I loop through the object and build a JavaScript `array` of the necessary object values ?  How do I select all of the values with the same key ?  Is it possible just to delete particular values out of the JSON response and rename the others as desired ? What is the best approach here ?

Below I have posted both the input and the desired output of what I would like to achieve.

## INPUT

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200,
        "requestId": "57c63303498e78d449981c2c"
    },
    "response": {
        "venues": [{
            "id": "430d0a00f964a5203e271fe3",
            "name": "Brooklyn Bridge Park",
            "location": {
                "address": "Main St",
                "crossStreet": "Plymouth St",
                "lat": 40.70303245363086,
                "lng": -73.99389265510275
            }
        }, {
            "id": "51eabef6498e10cf3aea7942",
            "name": "Brooklyn Bridge Park - Pier 2",
            "contact": {},
            "location": {
                "address": "Furman St",
                "crossStreet": "Brooklyn Bridge Park Greenway",
                "lat": 40.69957016220183,
                "lng": -73.99793274204788
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

## OUTPUT

```
[{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-73.99389265510277, 40.703032453630854]
    },
    "properties": {
        "id": "430d0a00f964a5203e271fe3",
        "name": "Brooklyn Bridge Park",
        "location": {
            "address": "Main St",
            "crossStreet": "Plymouth St",
            "lat": 40.703032453630854,
            "lng": -73.99389265510277
        }
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-73.9979327420479, 40.69957016220184]
    },
    "properties": {
        "id": "51eabef6498e10cf3aea7942",
        "name": "Brooklyn Bridge Park - Pier 2",
        "location": {
            "address": "Furman St",
            "crossStreet": "Brooklyn Bridge Park Greenway",
            "lat": 40.69957016220184,
            "lng": -73.9979327420479
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: Can you explain what your expected output is? What do you want as a result?

Comment: see the header "OUTPUT"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by saving the response into variable. Don't forget to `JSON.parse` it. Then you can do the following to convert it into your own format by using `Array#map` method.

```js
let obj = {
  "meta": {
    "code": 200,
    "requestId": "57c63303498e78d449981c2c"
  },
  "response": {
    "venues": [{
      "id": "430d0a00f964a5203e271fe3",
      "name": "Brooklyn Bridge Park",
      "location": {
        "address": "Main St",
        "crossStreet": "Plymouth St",
        "lat": 40.70303245363086,
        "lng": -73.99389265510275
      }
    }, {
      "id": "51eabef6498e10cf3aea7942",
      "name": "Brooklyn Bridge Park - Pier 2",
      "contact": {},
      "location": {
        "address": "Furman St",
        "crossStreet": "Brooklyn Bridge Park Greenway",
        "lat": 40.69957016220183,
        "lng": -73.99793274204788
      }
    }]
  }
};

let res = obj.response.venues.map((venue) => {
  let o = {};
  o.type = "feature";
  o.geometry = {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [venue.location.lng, venue.location.lat]
  };
  o.properties = venue;
  return o;
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the result from your request to the Foursquare API as a variable and then loop through it to get the information you need:

```
 var result =   {
        "meta": {
            "code": 200,
            "requestId": "57c63303498e78d449981c2c"
        },
        "response": {
            "venues": [{
                "id": "430d0a00f964a5203e271fe3",
                "name": "Brooklyn Bridge Park",
                "location": {
                    "address": "Main St",
                    "crossStreet": "Plymouth St",
                    "lat": 40.70303245363086,
                    "lng": -73.99389265510275
                }
            }, {
                "id": "51eabef6498e10cf3aea7942",
                "name": "Brooklyn Bridge Park - Pier 2",
                "contact": {},
                "location": {
                    "address": "Furman St",
                    "crossStreet": "Brooklyn Bridge Park Greenway",
                    "lat": 40.69957016220183,
                    "lng": -73.99793274204788
                }
            }]
        }
    }
for(i=0;i<result.response.venues.length;i++) {
  console.log(result.response.venues[i].name)
}
```

Console Result:
Brooklyn Bridge Park
Brooklyn Bridge Park - Pier 2

Instead of logging this to the console, you could then write the data into a new JS object the way you described in your output. Question is, do you really need to? The information is right there... rewriting it to a new object should not be necessary.

Comment: I am not sure if it is necessary, but geoJSON format is what is required by mapbox as specified in the output.  You think it would be better to simply rename the key values ?